# I need to get the equations for the circles and for the grids to match the picture with for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

This is my code so far but I can't seem to get the equations for the circles and for the grids correct enough to match my picture and I'm only allowed to use for loops, static methods, etc.
[image: Project Outcome needed]

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Illusion{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(500,400);
  panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
  Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
  //setup
  //circles
  drawCircle(g,0,0,90,3,1);
 // drawCircle(g,120,10,90,3,1);
 // drawCircle(g,250,50,80,5,1);
  //grids
  //drawGrid(g,10,120,100,10,2);
  //drawGrid(g,350,20,40,5,3);
  //drawGrid(g,230,160,50,5,4);
}


//equation for circles and diamonds
public static void drawCircle (Graphics g, int x, int y, int size,                   int circle, int grid) {

  //diamonds
 g.drawLine(x,y+size/2,x+size/2,y);
 g.drawLine(x+size/2,y,x+size,y+size/2);
  g.drawLine(x+size,y+size/2,x+size/2,y+size);
  g.drawLine(x+size/2,y+size,x,y+size/2);


  int circleHeight=size;
  int circleWidth=size;
  int circleX=x;
  int circleY=y;

   for (int i=0; i<circle; i++) {
     int subPos=size-i*(size/circle);
     int subSize=i*(size/(circle*2));
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.fillOval (x+ subPos,y+subPos,subSize,subSize);
     g.setColor (Color.BLACK);
     g.drawOval (x+subPos,y+subPos,subSize,subSize);
   }  
}
```

Comment: `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting works, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done

Comment: Design a single class which can generate a single "illusion" circle.  Re-use this as many times as you need to make up the rest of the requirements

Answer (score 2):

`Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting works, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done.

Start by defining a class which is capable of painting a single illusion, with parameters to control the number of circles and size.

```
public class EhrensteinIllusion {

    public EhrensteinIllusion() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D graphics, int dimeter, int circleCount) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, dimeter, dimeter);
        int divisions = dimeter / circleCount;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int circle = 0; circle < circleCount; circle++) {

            int size = divisions * (circle + 1);
            int x = (dimeter - size) / 2;
            int y = x;

            g2d.drawOval(x, y, size, size);

        }
        g2d.drawLine(dimeter / 2, 0, dimeter, dimeter / 2);
        g2d.drawLine(dimeter, dimeter / 2, dimeter / 2, dimeter);
        g2d.drawLine(dimeter / 2, dimeter, 0, dimeter / 2);
        g2d.drawLine(0, dimeter / 2, dimeter / 2, 0);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Now, note, I've not specified the x/y position, this is VERY important, as I'm going to use a feature of the `Graphics` API to do that instead.

Now, you need some way to be able paint these illusions...

[image: Part 03]

```
public class IllusionPane extends JPanel {

    private EhrensteinIllusion illusion = new EhrensteinIllusion();

    public IllusionPane() {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.translate(250, 50);
        illusion.paint(g2d, 80, 5);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

This satisfies the third series.

Now, all we need is a simple way to paint a grid.  All this does is repeatedly paints a `EhrensteinIllusion` at different positions, using the same technique above, by translation the origin point of the `Graphics` context

```
public class EhrensteinIllusionGrid {

    public void paint(Graphics2D graphics, int size, int circleCount, int rowsCols) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
        EhrensteinIllusion illusion = new EhrensteinIllusion();
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, size * rowsCols, size * rowsCols);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowsCols; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < rowsCols; col++) {
                Graphics2D gCopy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
                // New origin point
                gCopy.translate(col * size, row * size);
                illusion.paint(gCopy, size, circleCount);
                gCopy.dispose();
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Which you can use in the same way as you did the `EhrensteinIllusion` class, for example...

[image: Part 6]

```
public class IllusionPane extends JPanel {

    private EhrensteinIllusionGrid grid = new EhrensteinIllusionGrid();
    private EhrensteinIllusion illusion = new EhrensteinIllusion();

    public IllusionPane() {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.translate(250, 50);
        illusion.paint(g2d, 80, 5);
        g2d.dispose();
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.translate(230, 160);
        grid.paint(g2d, 50, 5, 4);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

This satisfies the sixth series.

Make sure you have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details