# Java: Squared Circles with Draw Panel

Tags: java, swing

I'm having difficulty with this problem, I am trying to make a bunch of groups of squares with circles in them, i can get the squared circles to start in the right place, but i am unable to add the extra squared circles. Not all of the code is included, but everything else is correct i just need help with creating multiples copies.. also I need this to be done with the graphics draw panel

I can get this

[image: my squared circles]

but i need this 
[image: I need this]

this is the code i'm using right now... any tips would be greatly helpful

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        drawSquaredCircles( g, 0,   0,   100, 5, 1 );
        drawSquaredCircles( g, 10,  120, 24,  4, 5 );
        drawSquaredCircles( g, 150, 20,  40,  5, 6 );
        drawSquaredCircles( g, 130, 275, 36,  3, 3 );

    }

    // Draws a square figure, at the given x/y position.
    public static void drawSquaredCircles( Graphics g, int x, int y, int subfigureSize, int numCircles, int numRowsCols ) {

        drawCircles(g, x , y, subfigureSize, numCircles);
        //add width and hight

        for(int i = 0; i < numRowsCols; i++){

            drawCircles(g,x , y, subfigureSize, numCircles);
        }
```

Comment: Basically, this is the same problem demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170372/i-need-to-get-the-equations-for-the-circles-and-for-the-grids-to-match-the-pictu/34170579#34170579) (it has squares instead of a cross, but the basic design/concept is the same as is the answer)

Comment: `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting works! See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done

Comment: 1)  Your current for loop just draws in a single spot, you need to use your loop variable 2) you'll need to use a double for loop to draw rows and columns of the square.

Comment: @Cricket_007 I'm still confused, sorry, I'm still new to this. So I'm supposed to use a nested loop, I have tried this but keep getting the exact same thing when just using a for loop                                                                        For (i=0; i < numRowsCols; i++) {                                                                                                    For (j=0; j < ?????; j++)

Comment: You can think of the i variable as the rows and the j variable as the columns, so the question marks are also `numRowsCols`

Comment: @cricket_007   for(int i = 0; i < numRowsCols; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < numRowsCols; j++){
            drawCircles(g,x , y, subfigureSize, numCircles);
           }
        }
this is what i used and it is still giving me the same solution... this is getting frustrating i've been tinkering around with it for a couple hours and i still can't figure it out

Comment: X and Y need to use I and J. Do you not see that you are drawing in the same spot like I said? Do `(x + 20*i)` where 20 is the width of the square

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you, i feel so stupid, im sorry to have bugged you with this, i think i've been working on this for too long and was just overlooking something so simple.  Thank you very much again